# How to remove duplicated commit from remote after ran git filter-branch

Tags: git, github

I was cleaning up the repo from sensitive data, so to remove the file server/newrelic.js from all the commits I've used the filter-branch command.

When the command finished I messed up, because instead of force the push, I did a pull and then i pushed the changes. 
The result was that all the commits are now duplicated and I don't know how to remove them. 
So i merged the old chain of commits with the new chain of commits, instead of force-overwriting the old repository to discard all the old commits.

```sh
git filter-branch --index-filter "git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch server/newrelic.js" HEAD
```

I have more than 2800 commit after duplication and the rebase is not an option. 
I hope that with another filter-branch I can remove all the duplicated commits, but I would like to be sure that I don't mess up anymore.

Any help is really appreciated.

[image: here picture by graph topology]

Answer (score 1):

#### In this case, you just want to do a `git reset --hard`

For your particular case, assuming the branch is named `master` and you're on it right now:

```
git reset --hard master~1
git log                     # make sure everything looks right
git push -f origin master   # if everything looks right, now you can push
```

The `master~1` can be spelled other ways, e.g., `master^` or `master~` or `HEAD~` all work (except that if you are on Windows, some of the shells like to "eat" the `^` character for their own use).

#### Background

Before filtering, you had:

```
<long-chain-of-commits, with maybe some branch-and-merges>   <-- master
```

After filtering, you really had this, in your local repository:

```
<long-chain-of-commits>   [to be discarded]

<copied-long-chain-of-commits>   <-- master
```

The *copied* commits have different hash IDs.  The original commits are all still there, unchanged.  It's just that if you start with the name `master` and work backwards, as Git does, you won't *see* the originals.  You will see only the new copies.

Of course, the *other* Git repository involved here still had the originals too, under *its* name `master`.  So you ran `git pull` which ran `git fetch` and then `git merge`.  The `git fetch` first asked them: *What commits do you have that I don't?  Gimme!*  If you had managed to actually discard the original commits at this point, that brought them all back.  If they were still there, just unused, this step did nothing.  The `git fetch` then set your `origin/master` to remember the last commit in the long chain:<sup>1</sup>

```
<long-chain-of-commits>   <-- origin/master

<copied-long-chain-of-commits>   <-- master
```

The second half of `git pull` is to run `git merge`, so your Git ran a `git merge`.<sup>2</sup>  That made a new *merge* commit on your `master`:

```
<long-chain-of-commits>   <-- origin/master
                       \
<copied-long-chain>-----M   <-- master
```

That's where all the duplicates show up.

To fix the problem, you just need to get rid of the merge commit `M`.  Using `git reset` can do this.<sup>3</sup>  It also drops any commits *after* the dropped commit, but there are no such commits, so that's no problem.  The syntax for this kind of `git reset` is:

```
git reset --hard <commit-specifier>
```

where the *`commit-specifier`* can be anything that locates the commit you *want* your branch name—I'm assuming it's `master`—to identify.  A branch is just *the commit the branch name points to, plus all the commits that come before it via parent hash IDs.*  The commit you want is the one right before `M`—as its *first* parent, not its second one.  So that's `master^1` (not `master^2`), which can also be spelled `master~1`.  (Or, you can run `git log` and then cut-and-paste the correct commit hash ID, if you like.)

Once you have done the reset, you have:

```
<long-chain-of-commits>   <-- origin/master
                       \
                        M   [to be discarded]
                       /
   <copied-long-chain>   <-- master
```

The no-longer-useful merge commit `M` will float around uselessly for at least 30 days by default, in case you decide it's not useless and want it back.  Then the parts of Git that remember old commits for a while<sup>4</sup> will forget its hash ID, after which a subsequent `git gc` will remove `M` for real—whenever `git gc` actually runs, that is.

Git frequently runs `git gc --auto` for you, to clean up, but with `--auto`, `git gc` checks to see if it's *time* to run for real yet.  If not, `git gc --auto` just exits instantly, without doing anything.  Otherwise, `git gc --auto` spins off a background task that does the actual `git gc`, which actually cleans up.

---

<sup>1</sup>You might already have had an `origin/master` that already remembered the last commit in the original chain, so that the original commits were not ready to be discarded yet.  The effect is still the same: the `git fetch` makes sure that you have these commits, and that `origin/master` identifies the *last* one.

<sup>2</sup>This merge has particular arguments, and in various cases, sometimes you'll get a complaint about unrelated histories and the merge will *fail*.  In this case, obviously you didn't.  The reason isn't that important here, although it matters a lot when you *want* the merge to work. :-)

<sup>3</sup>Any such dropped commits aren't really *gone* yet.  They're just no longer *on the branch*, as the branch name now points to whichever commit you choose.

<sup>4</sup>These are Git's *reflogs*.  Use `git reflog` to view the reflog for `HEAD`, for instance.

Comment: It worked doing the reset and the force push, so if i check on github now i have half of the commits and on git log the dups are not visible, but as you said, there is something stored that still have that commits (even if i clone the repo from scratch). If i run `git show <old dup commit id>` i still see the details of the dup commit. I tried to run `git gc` (it worked once) but then i get an error: failed to run repack. How can i get rid of those old commits if `git gc` doesn't work?

Comment: you can check the github repos https://www.github.com/daton89/safety-platform.git (original) https://www.github.com/daton89/safetyclone.git (mirror for test)

Comment: I don't know why your `git gc` is getting a repack error, but that's anywhere from mildly alarming (nothing really wrong, just that you're low on memory) to very alarming (Git is tripping over corrupted data). But the gc *won't* discard objects that are still in use, e.g., via reflogs, nor anything that's not at least 14 days old by default. Unless you're low on resources (memory or disk space) it's usually easiest to just let Git take care of these things later. However, the repack error is worth looking into.